# The problem of iterative skepticism

Tags: epistemology, skepticism

I mean the following tactics:

Christina: *"There is a tree outside in the garden."*

René: *"I grant that this might be right, and even that your sensory information would justify your belief. So maybe you know there is a tree in the garden. But you certainly cannot know **that you know** that there is a tree in the garden! So did you really know it in the first place?"*

This problem is a bit different from the epistemic-closure type attack, and let's call it *iterative skepticism,* for lack of a better word.

I find this similarly unnerving, though. I agree that we have the strong intuition that knowledge must be **infallible** to count as knowledge. Still, I don't see how the mere logical possibility of error can ever be excluded. The evidence would need to be so strong that it *entails* the belief it supports, which is never the case for all normal, common real-world beliefs.

René Descartes managed to convince himself that non-trivial, infallible knowledge was indeed in reach for humans, via his clear and distinct perception. But this was obviously invalid, and it's absurd to believe another such attempt could succeed.

So how can we answer *iterative skepticism?* Do we need to drop infallibility as a criterion for knowledge? But the famous "You will not win the lottery" is likely going to be true, and has a justification, but we would never talk about knowledge here. Just a guess, with very good odds to be right. So it seems infallibility can't be simply dropped.

Does some more moderate version of "infallibility" suffice, which means something less than the **logical** impossibility of error?

Comment: This sort of iteration does not work on standard knowledge theories. All iterated beliefs are plausibly justified so the only question is about their truth. But the truth of the ground belief makes iterated beliefs true all at once. Either they are all knowledge or none of them is, so René's parsing is incoherent.

Comment: Your problem has a better word called KK thesis...

Comment: @Conifold: This is getting a bit into the weeds, but I think the argument OP is trying to make is that knowledge requires (at least - see Gettier) justified *true* belief, and while we may hold a justified belief, we do not *know* that belief unless it is actually true, which suggests that meta-knowledge requires infallibility in a way that regular knowledge does not. IMHO [deflationism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-deflationary/) disposes of that argument (knowing X is the same as knowing that X is true), but other truth theories might have a problem there.

Comment: @Kevin Right. IEP has a good discussion of this under the [KK principle](https://iep.utm.edu/kk-princ/#H2). Traditional (internalist) theories assume that mental states are "luminous" to their owners and "one is always in a position to know whether one’s beliefs are warranted". In contrast, reliabilists reject luminosity, "if one’s belief that p is produced by a reliable process that one knows nothing about, then one may have no way of knowing that this belief constitutes knowledge, and thus no way of knowing that one knows that p." But KK failure there is a feature and not a "problem".

Comment: @Conifold IMHO there's a difference between "Ch has a true, justified belief that there is a tree in the garden" and (after one iteration) "Ch has a true, justified belief that her belief that there is a tree in the garden is justified and true". The problem now is that we got into a position of having a belief involving that word "true", which seems to be stronger when regarded as correspondence. Does the iterated statement, really hold? I'd say NO, we can't say she's justified to believe making no error, since even if errors are very unlikely, remain a possibility.

Comment: As the above examples show, you need to be very clear as to what your "know" involves. "I'd say" comes from vague/ambiguous colloquial usage and intuitions, there would be no need for it when the meaning of "know" is explicitly fleshed out. And what comes out then is that in those theories where "iterated skepticism" might be a problem it does not arise, and in those where it does arise it is not a problem.

Comment: @Conifold obviously it depends on the meaning of "know", but something more should be said about it than just this. It's *prima facie* different to say something about the belief *and* reality, compared to just reality. The former entails more than the latter, except if your special definition of "know" deflates it.